# Plugin for TensorRT

Tags: tensorflow, tensorrt

I have Tensorflow ops ResizeArea, Select, Fill, and Equal used in my Tensorflow model.
When model was converted to uff, got warnings as

```
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: ResizeArea yet.
Converting upsample_heatmat as custom op: ResizeArea
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: Select yet.
Converting Select as custom op: Select
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: Fill yet.
Converting zeros_like as custom op: Fill
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: Equal yet.
Converting Equal as custom op: Equal
```

So plugins are created for ResizeArea, Select, Fill, and Equal.

Then plugins are mapped to Tensorflow ops as

```
class ModelData(object):
    INPUT_NAME = "image"
    EQUAL_NAME = "Equal"
    SELECT_NAME = "Select"
    PMAT_NAME = "upsample_pafmat"
    ZERO_LIKE = "zeros_like"
    HMAT_NAME = "upsample_heatmat"
    OUTPUT_NAME = "Openpose/output"

def prepare_namespace_plugin_map():
    # In this sample, the only operation that is not supported by TensorRT
    # is tf.nn.relu6, so we create a new node which will tell UffParser which
    # plugin to run and with which arguments in place of tf.nn.relu6.


    # The "clipMin" and "clipMax" fields of this TensorFlow node will be parsed by createPlugin,
    # and used to create a CustomClipPlugin with the appropriate parameters.
    trt_resizearea = gs.create_plugin_node(name="trt_resizearea", op="ResizeAreaPlugin", in_width=80.0, in_height=60.0, in_channel=3.0, upscale=4.0)
    trt_fill = gs.create_plugin_node(name="trt_fill", op="FillPlugin", in_width=320.0, in_height=240.0, in_channel=3.0, value=0.0)#fill 0
    trt_equal = gs.create_plugin_node(name="trt_equal", op="EqualPlugin", in_width=320.0, in_height=240.0, in_channel=3.0)
    trt_select = gs.create_plugin_node(name="trt_select", op="SelectPlugin", in_width=320.0, in_height=240.0, value=0.0)
    namespace_plugin_map = {
        ModelData.SELECT_NAME: trt_select,
        ModelData.EQUAL_NAME: trt_equal,
        ModelData.PMAT_NAME: trt_resizearea,
        ModelData.HMAT_NAME: trt_resizearea,
        ModelData.ZERO_LIKE: trt_fill
    }
    return namespace_plugin_map

def model_to_uff(model_path):
    # Transform graph using graphsurgeon to map unsupported TensorFlow
    # operations to appropriate TensorRT custom layer plugins
    dynamic_graph = gs.DynamicGraph(model_path)
    dynamic_graph.collapse_namespaces(prepare_namespace_plugin_map())
    # Save resulting graph to UFF file
    output_uff_path = model_path_to_uff_path(model_path)
    uff.from_tensorflow(
        dynamic_graph.as_graph_def(),
        [ModelData.OUTPUT_NAME],
        output_filename=output_uff_path,
        text=True
    )
    return output_uff_path

def model_path_to_uff_path(model_path):
    uff_path = os.path.splitext(model_path)[0] + ".uff"
    return uff_path
```

Why I still have warnings as

```
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: ResizeAreaPlugin yet.
Converting trt_resizearea as custom op: ResizeAreaPlugin
W0808 17:44:51.442725 139793630279424 deprecation_wrapper.py:119] From /home/coie/Data/coie/Softwares/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/uff/converters/tensorflow/converter.py:179: The name tf.AttrValue is deprecated. Please use tf.compat.v1.AttrValue instead.

Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: SelectPlugin yet.
Converting trt_select as custom op: SelectPlugin
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: FillPlugin yet.
Converting trt_fill as custom op: FillPlugin
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: EqualPlugin yet.
Converting trt_equal as custom op: EqualPlugin
```

What could be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

My solution was correct.
Eventhough, plugins are successfully mapped to Tensorflow ops, warnings are still produced.
We can check whether plugins are successfully loaded in running TensorRT engine by printing in the plugin APIs.